# <referece name="root"> does not work

Tags: template, overrides, design

following [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento#dokuwiki__top) article I created:

```
app/desgin/frontend/<my_template>/
    +template/page/main.phtml
    +layout/local.xml
```

In `local.xml` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default> 
    <remove name="right.poll"/>
    <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
    <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
    <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/main.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setIsHandle">
                <applied>1</applied>
            </action>
        </reference>

   </default>
</layout>
```

`main.phtml` contains:

```
<?php die(); ?>
```

The remove statements work, but the application **does not die**. For test purposes I copied the whole content of `app/design/base/default/template/page/3columns.phtml` into `main.phtml` and added some `<h1></h1>` to gain visual feedback, but nothing appears.

Am I missing some settings in the backend (the design is set to `<my_template>`)?

**UPDATE**

I could finally make magento use the `main.phtml` by adding some lines to `local.xml`

```
<page_three_columns>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/main.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setIsHandle">
            <applied>1</applied>
        </action>
    </reference>    
</page_three_columns>
```

I just searched `app/design/frontend/base/default/page.xml` where I found several calls like the one above all the following the `<page_*>` syntax, so I guess that this connected to the layout settings of CMS pages and the internal `handles`.

Well, however, going on searching, if found [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates) article and I guess that is what I want to do, or in other words, have to do for magento.

Answer (score 1):

The structure has to be `app/desgin/frontend/<my_package>/<my_template>/` and not `app/desgin/frontend/<my_template>/`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the template in the `<default>` tag means that it will be overwritten by every other page handle coming after that.

For example if in the catalog.xml there is a template set for `<catalog_product_view>` your settings from the default will be overwritten by that.

Creating a new type of template `page_three_columns` is one way to go about it as you've stated in your original question another way to do it is by targeting specific page handles for each page you want to change the layout of